# Installing Kivy using cmd results in "ERROR: Dependency ... not resolved"

Tags: python, cmd, kivy, kivy-language

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\SULTAN~1\kivy_venv\Scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Sultan Mehmood\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9dfsjn67\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Sultan Mehmood\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9dfsjn67\\kivy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Sultan Mehmood\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9dfsjn67\kivy\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Sultan Mehmood\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9dfsjn67\kivy\
    Complete output (394 lines):
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'C:\Users\SULTAN~1\kivy_venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Sultan Mehmood\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-4mzjiac1\\cython\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Sultan Mehmood\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-4mzjiac1\\cython\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Sultan Mehmood\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-z6kn3m2w'
           cwd: C:\Users\Sultan Mehmood\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-4mzjiac1\cython\
      Complete output (321 lines):
      Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8
      copying cython.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\CodeWriter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\Coverage.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\Debugging.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\Shadow.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\StringIOTree.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\TestUtils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\Utils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython
      copying Cython\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\BuildExecutable.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\Cythonize.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\Dependencies.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\Distutils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\Inline.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\IpythonMagic.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Build
      copying Cython\Build\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Build
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\AnalysedTreeTransforms.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Annotate.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\AutoDocTransforms.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Buffer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Builtin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\CmdLine.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Code.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\CodeGeneration.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\CythonScope.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\DebugFlags.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Errors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\ExprNodes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\FlowControl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\FusedNode.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Future.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Interpreter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Lexicon.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Main.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\MemoryView.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\ModuleNode.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Naming.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Nodes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Optimize.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Options.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\ParseTreeTransforms.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Parsing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Pipeline.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\PyrexTypes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Pythran.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Scanning.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\StringEncoding.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Symtab.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\TreeFragment.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\TreePath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\TypeInference.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\TypeSlots.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\UtilityCode.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\UtilNodes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\Visitor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Runtime
      copying Cython\Runtime\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Runtime
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Distutils
      copying Cython\Distutils\build_ext.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Distutils
      copying Cython\Distutils\extension.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Distutils
      copying Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Distutils
      copying Cython\Distutils\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Distutils
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Debugger
      copying Cython\Debugger\Cygdb.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Debugger
      copying Cython\Debugger\DebugWriter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Debugger
      copying Cython\Debugger\libcython.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Debugger
      copying Cython\Debugger\libpython.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Debugger
      copying Cython\Debugger\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Debugger
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Debugger\Tests
      copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\TestLibCython.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Debugger\Tests
      copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\test_libcython_in_gdb.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Debugger\Tests
      copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\test_libpython_in_gdb.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Debugger\Tests
      copying Cython\Debugger\Tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Debugger\Tests
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Actions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\DFA.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Errors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Lexicons.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Machines.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Regexps.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Scanners.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Timing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Traditional.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\Transitions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Plex
      copying Cython\Plex\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Plex
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Tests
      copying Cython\Tests\TestCodeWriter.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Tests
      copying Cython\Tests\TestCythonUtils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Tests
      copying Cython\Tests\TestJediTyper.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Tests
      copying Cython\Tests\TestStringIOTree.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Tests
      copying Cython\Tests\xmlrunner.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Tests
      copying Cython\Tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Tests
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Build\Tests
      copying Cython\Build\Tests\TestCyCache.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Build\Tests
      copying Cython\Build\Tests\TestInline.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Build\Tests
      copying Cython\Build\Tests\TestIpythonMagic.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Build\Tests
      copying Cython\Build\Tests\TestStripLiterals.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Build\Tests
      copying Cython\Build\Tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Build\Tests
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestBuffer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestCmdLine.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestFlowControl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestGrammar.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestMemView.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestParseTreeTransforms.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestSignatureMatching.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestTreeFragment.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestTreePath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestTypes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestUtilityLoad.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\TestVisitor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      copying Cython\Compiler\Tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler\Tests
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Tempita
      copying Cython\Tempita\compat3.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Tempita
      copying Cython\Tempita\_looper.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Tempita
      copying Cython\Tempita\_tempita.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Tempita
      copying Cython\Tempita\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Tempita
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\pyximport
      copying pyximport\pyxbuild.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyximport
      copying pyximport\pyximport.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyximport
      copying pyximport\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\pyximport
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes
      copying Cython\Includes\openmp.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\array.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\bool.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\buffer.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\bytearray.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\bytes.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\ceval.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\cobject.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\complex.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\datetime.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\dict.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\exc.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\float.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\function.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\getargs.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\instance.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\int.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\iterator.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\list.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\long.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\longintrepr.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\mapping.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\mem.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\method.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\module.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\number.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\object.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\oldbuffer.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pycapsule.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pylifecycle.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pystate.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\pythread.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\ref.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\sequence.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\set.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\slice.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\string.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\tuple.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\type.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\unicode.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\version.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\weakref.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      copying Cython\Includes\cpython\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\cpython
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_bool.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_buffer.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_bytes.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_cobject.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_complex.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_dict.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_exc.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_float.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_function.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_getargs.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_instance.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_int.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_iterator.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_list.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_long.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_mapping.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_mem.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_method.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_module.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_number.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_object.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_oldbuffer.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_pycapsule.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_ref.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_sequence.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_set.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_string.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_tuple.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_type.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_unicode.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_version.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\python_weakref.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\stdio.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\stdlib.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      copying Cython\Includes\Deprecated\stl.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\Deprecated
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\errno.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\float.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\limits.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\locale.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\math.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\setjmp.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\signal.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\stddef.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdint.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdio.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\stdlib.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\string.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\time.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      copying Cython\Includes\libc\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libc
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\algorithm.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\cast.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\complex.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\deque.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\limits.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\list.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      copying Cython\Includes\libcpp\memory.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\libcpp
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\numpy
      copying Cython\Includes\numpy\math.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\numpy
      copying Cython\Includes\numpy\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\numpy
      creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\dlfcn.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\fcntl.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\ioctl.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\mman.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\resource.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\select.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\signal.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\stat.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\stdio.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\stdlib.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\strings.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\time.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\types.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\unistd.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\wait.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Includes\posix\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Includes\posix
      copying Cython\Compiler\Code.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\FlowControl.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Compiler\ParseTreeTransforms.pxd -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Compiler
      copying Cython\Utility\CppConvert.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\MemoryView.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\TestCythonScope.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\TestCyUtilityLoader.pyx -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utili
      copying Cython\Utility\Embed.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Exceptions.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\ExtensionTypes.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\FunctionArguments.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\ImportExport.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\MemoryView_C.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\ModuleSetupCode.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\ObjectHandling.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Optimize.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Overflow.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Printing.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\Profile.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\StringTools.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\TestUtilityLoader.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\TypeConversion.c -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\arrayarray.h -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      copying Cython\Utility\CppSupport.cpp -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Cython\Utility
      running build_ext
      building 'Cython.Plex.Scanners' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for cython
    ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "C:\Users\SULTAN~1\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
         subprocess.check_call(cmd)
       File "C:\Users\Sultan Mehmood\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
     subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\SULTAN~1\\kivy_venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\SULTAN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpmxoyefbj', '--quiet', '--find-links', 'https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden/archive/master.zip', 'cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.10,>=0.24']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
       File "C:\Users\Sultan Mehmood\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9dfsjn67\kivy\setup.py", line 1073, in <module>
         setup(
         resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
       File "C:\Users\SULTAN~1\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 780, in resolve
         return self.obtain(req, installer)
       File "C:\Users\SULTAN~1\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1077, in obtain
         return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
       File "C:\Users\SULTAN~1\kivy_venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\installer.py", line 130, in fetch_build_egg
         raise DistutilsError(str(e))
     distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['C:\\Users\\SULTAN~1\\kivy_venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', 'C:\\Users\\SULTAN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpmxoyefbj', '--quiet', '--find-links', 'https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden/archive/master.zip', 'cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.10,>=0.24']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    Using setuptools
    User distribution detected, avoid portable command.
    Using this graphics system: OpenGL
    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

    WARNING: A problem occurred while running pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl2 SDL2_ttf SDL2_image SDL2_mixer (code 1)

    b"'pkg-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

    ERROR: Dependency for context.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for compiler.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for context_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for fbo.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for gl_instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for instructions.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for opengl_utils.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
    ERROR: Dependency for shader.pyx not resolved: config.pxi
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no support for Python 3.8 yet.

You can see the issue being tracked here:
https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6563

If you absolutely need to use kivy on python 3.8, there are some things you can try:

You can download and install a custom wheel at: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#kivy

Or you can  you can install kivy master using

`pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/`